# Reading a list of links in xml

Tags: c#, xml

Im trying to read a list of links that i fetched from the internet:

```
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(e.Result)))
                {  
                    reader.ReadToFollowing("link");                    

                    while (reader.HasValue)
                    {
                        .... read node logic ....

                        reader.ReadToNextSibling("link");
                    }                    
                }
```

but my while quits :( what is the magic if i want to go thru all the `<link>`'s?

Comment: Any reason you particularly want to use `XmlReader`? What version of .NET are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
XElement x = XElement.Parse(e.Result);
IEnumerable<XElement> links = x.Elements("link");
foreach(XElement link in links)
{
    .... read node logic ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use reader.Read() to perform while

```
    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(e.Result)))
            {
                reader.ReadToFollowing("link");

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    .... read node logic ....
                     reader.ReadToNextSibling("link");
                }                    
            }
```